# Ubuntu 18.04: FontConfig update not possible (fc-cache: FcDirCacheCreateUUID)

Tags: 18.04, updates, fonts

I can not update fontconfig. Whatever I (or Google) can think of it will return the same error:

```
> sudo apt-get upgrade
[...]
fontconfig (2.12.6-0ubuntu2.3) wird eingerichtet ...
Regenerating fonts cache... failed.
See /var/log/fontconfig.log for more information.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes fontconfig (--configure):
Unterprozess installiertes fontconfig-Skript des Paketes post-installation gab den Fehler-Ausgangsstatus 1 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
fontconfig
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Sorry for the german parts of the error message.

Yes, I already googled it and I also tried the following solutions:

- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libfontconfig1 libfontconfig1-dev`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade libfontconfig1`
- `sudo apt-get install --reinstall --purge fontconfig-config`
- Switching the package sources and update the dcaches.

None of them solves the problem.

`/var/log/fonts` contains a single line

```
fc-cache: symbol lookup error: fc-cache: undefined symbol: FcDirCacheCreateUUID
```

I am pretty sure I have spent over two hours googling and trying all combinations of fontconfig, fc-cache and FcDirCacheCreateUUID AND none of the suggested solutions work.

I am really getting desperate since this issue is blocking installing very basic software.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=722300 This poster had some old libraries hanging around. Same symptoms.

Comment: Might be. I just have no clue how to figure out which package is the correct one and how to remove it apart from just deleting the files from my harddrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After manually removing fontconfig:i386 I apparently solved by reinstalling it:

sudo apt-get install fontconfig:i386

No idea why this has worked but apparently it did.

Comment: Worked for me in this form `sudo apt-get install --reinstall fontconfig`, double check with `fc-cache -f -v`